# Perform text animation by splitting text, but retain line breaks

Tags: javascript

I have created a function that maps over a sentence (provided by a CMS) and adds containers to each word. Splitting each word at spaces.

Now, some words will require line breaks, but my function is wiping them out, and I am not quite sure how I am going to retain line breaks in this case.

The demo below displays the issue I am having. The second one, although originally having a line break, has it removed when the function runs.

The breaks are coming from WP WYSIWYG, using a return. The field is using ACF and using the 'Automatically add 
' option for new lines. Dev tools interprets/displays the original output as

`<h1>This Is<br>Line Broken</h1>`

Any ideas or advice of how to retain the breaks will be appreciated. For the purpose of my animations, each word will require the markup in the return value of $reformatedText

```js
let $textAreaContent;
let $splitText;
let $reformatedText;
let $delayTime;
let $delayValue;
let $textAreas = document.querySelectorAll('.stagger-text');


function setDelayValue(curCount) {
  $delayTime = 0.075;
  return parseFloat(curCount * $delayTime).toFixed(3);
}

function createStaggerContainers($textArea) {
  $textAreaContent = $textArea;
  $splitText = $textAreaContent.innerText.split(/\s|<br>/g);

  $reformatedText = $splitText.map((item, i, arr) => {
    $delayValue = setDelayValue(i);
    return `<span class="stagger__container">
              <span class="stagger__text" style="animation-delay: ${$delayValue}s">${arr.length - 1 === i ? item : `${item}&nbsp;`}</span>
            </span>`;
  }).join('');

  $textAreaContent.innerText = '';
  $textAreaContent.innerHTML = $reformatedText;
}

if ($textAreas && $textAreas.length) {
  $textAreas.forEach(($textArea) => {
    createStaggerContainers($textArea);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="stagger-text">Some text here</div>
<div class="stagger-text">This has line<br> breaks</div>
```

Comment: What's causing the breaks? Do they exist in the original content or are they generated by the browser's layout engine?

Comment: So the breaks are coming from WP WYSIWYG, using a return. The field is using ACF and using the 'Automatically add <br>' option for new lines. Dev tools interprets/displays the original output as `<h1>This Is<br>Line Broken</h1>`